# Listview carrega os itens portanto sem texto

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

O ListView carrega os itens (inclusive para possível edição), mas sem o texto do item:

[[image: Função que realiza carregamento do ListView[1]]

[image: Classe Company]

[image: Teste: Carrega 3 linhas do ListView, inclusive para editar mas sem texto]

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde Felipe, segue um exemplo de como fazer uma estrutura de listview,

Classe Modelo

```
  public class EmpresaCliente
  {
    public int IDEmpresa { get; set; }
    public int IDCadastroCliente { get; set; }
    public int IDCadastroEmpresa { get; set; }
    public int IDStatusEmail { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Cnpj { get; set; }
    public string SituacaoEmpresa { get; set; }
    public string StatusEmail { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
  }
```

XAML

```
<ListView IsVisible="False" HeightRequest="-1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" ItemsSource="{Binding EmpresaCliente}" SeparatorColor="#010d47"  RowHeight="120" x:Name="lvEmpresa" ItemTapped="LvEmpresa_ItemTapped" SelectionMode="None">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ViewCell>
                                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">



                                                        <Label Text="{Binding Nome}" TextColor="#010d47" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding Cnpj, Converter={Helpers:NullValueBoolConverter}}">
                                                        <Label Text="CNPJ da Empresa:" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding Cnpj}"></Label>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <Label Text="Situação da Empresa:" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding SituacaoEmpresa}" TextColor="Red" IsVisible="{Binding SituacaoEmpresa, Converter={Helpers:NullValueBoolConverter}}">
                                                            <Label.Triggers>
                                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding SituacaoEmpresa}" Value="ATIVA">
                                                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding SituacaoEmpresa}" Value="INATIVA">
                                                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger>  
                                                            </Label.Triggers>
                                                        </Label>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  IsVisible="{Binding StatusEmail, Converter={Helpers:NullValueBoolConverter}}">

                                                        <Label Text="Status:" FontAttributes="Bold"></Label>
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding StatusEmail}">
                                                            <Label.Triggers>
                                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding StatusEmail}" Value="ENVIADO">
                                                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding StatusEmail}" Value="AGUARDANDO ENVIO">
                                                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#facd34"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding StatusEmail}" Value="AGUARDANDO RETORNO">
                                                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#facd34"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding StatusEmail}" Value="SOLICITADO PPP POR E-MAIL">
                                                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#facd34"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding StatusEmail}" Value="RECEBIDO">
                                                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding StatusEmail}" Value="ENQUADRADO POR FUNÇÃO">
                                                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#facd34"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding StatusEmail}" Value="AGUARDANDO LIGAÇÃO">
                                                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#facd34"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding StatusEmail}" Value="SOLICITADO POR TELEFONE">
                                                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding StatusEmail}" Value="AGUARDANDO PESQUISA">
                                                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="DarkRed"/>
                                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                            </Label.Triggers>
                                                        </Label>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </ViewCell>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
```

C#

```
    public async void Populate()
    {

        try
        {
            var lista = await BuscarEmpresasAtreladas();
            if (lista.Count >= 1)
            {
                lvEmpresa.ItemsSource = lista;
                lvEmpresa.IsVisible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                lvEmpresa.IsVisible = false;
                lbEmpty.IsVisible = true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Ocorreu um erro", "Por favor verifique sua conexão com a internet", "OK");
        }
    }
```

No caso de fazer o design direto no C# tem que seguir o mesmo modelo de binding com o nome de cada elemento do Modelo ex: {Binding Nome}, {Bindind Cnpj} e etc.